# Google Spreadsheet API ListQuery by row id (row.getId) possible?

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When you add a row to a Google spreadsheet using the listfeed service as shown below, you receive a bunch of row metadata back.  One of those values is the row id.

```
row = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);
System.out.println("row id " + row.getId());  // server generated row id attached
```

Is it possible to create a list query at a later time that returns only this row, using that metadata (e.g. the row id?)

Just some background on what I am trying to do.   Multiple instances of the app will be using the same spreadsheet, and I think it would be far more efficient to use the server generated unique ID to retrieve the row later (if possible), rather than have my app first query the sheet to see what unique IDs are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ListDemo.java. I think it demos most (maybe all) of the main ListFeed features. Search is the closest I can see, so if you have a primary key this would work.

https://github.iu.edu/weng/IncrementalLearning/blob/master/gdata/java/sample/spreadsheet/list/ListDemo.java

I have not tried this one, but CellDemo.java was easy to setup.

Comment: Thank you the example was very helpful.